# Meaning of "don't necessarily think"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage, sentence-usage

What do English speakers exactly mean when they say:

> I don't **necessarily think** that

or:

> I don't think that someone is **necessarily** a bad person

Comment: You can get this question reopened by doing including some research explaining what you learned when you looked up _necessarily_ in a dictionary. We don't mind helping people when they get stuck, but you need to first put forth a good-faith effort and include those results in your question.

Answer (score 2):

This construction denies positively asserting something, while implying that the speaker thinks it probable, or at least possible.

> I don't think that Joe is NECESSARILY a bad person.

The evidence presented or the situation under discussion does not **prove** that Joe is a bad person, and the speaker is not willing to assert that joe is a bad person. However, it is implied that the facts at least suggest that Joe is a bad parson, that other explanations are less likely.

> I don't *NECESSARILY THINK* that people who say Bacon wrote Shakespeare are nuts.

They may simply be misled or have other reasons, but this is not a positive statement about such people. The speaker implies that it is more likely than not that such people are nuts, even if it isn't really proved.

Answer (score 0):

It means that one should not rely on assumptions when making a judgment. Examples: "Just because it's raining today doesn't necessarily mean the weather will be bad tomorrow."  "Just because he won an award doesn't necessarily make him a good person".

Comment: Yes, but when "necessarily" is **stressed**, and particularly when used along with think, I believe it usually implies "unproved but likely".

Comment: @DavidSiegel agreed. Two heads are better than one . . . .